# Android 4.x: NullPointerException with sendMultipartText

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, sms, multipart

All of a sudden my widely-used app has started crashing when attempting to send a multipart text. This is after 1000s of users, so we are not looking at a simple bug (I think!). Its definitely correlated to `4.1.2`, definitely `4.x` versions.

My desperate work-around has been to trap the `NullPointerException` and then send this multipart as multiple standard (< 160) texts (ugh, I know). The stack trace is below, even looking into the Android source hasn't helped.

---

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1431)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
at com.android.internal.telephony.ISms$Stub$Proxy.sendMultipartText(ISms.java:930)
at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(SmsManager.java:411)
at com.gearandroid.phoneleashfree.PhoneLeashTransmitter.sendSMS(PhoneLeashTransmitter.java:1395)
at com.gearandroid.phoneleashfree.PhoneLeashTransmitter.sendFromSMSQueue(PhoneLeashTransmitter.java:1316)
```

---

Thanks!

PVS

Answer (score 0):

I think I meet the same problem as yours, and my solution is from https://github.com/WhisperSystems/TextSecure/issues/418 and https://code.google.com/p/gtalksms/issues/detail?id=341
You didn't offer your code, the reason may different, as I know, it may because the PendingIntent offered to sendMultipartTextMessage is null; or didn't add  PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT.

My soluthon is 
1. add exception to avoid the app from crash;
2. Add PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT and here is my code:

```
for(String msg : msgs){
     Intent sender = new Intent(BtSmsService.SMS_RESULT);
     sender.putExtra("PHONE", mPhoneNumber);
     sender.putExtra("MSG", mSms);
     sender.putExtra("IDX", idx++);
     sender.putExtra("TOTAL", msgs.size());
     sender.putExtra("ID", firstime);
     PendingIntent mPi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(BtSmsService.this,
       alarmSign + idx, sender, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);//Here, I use 0 before fixed
     mPis.add(mPi);
    }
smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(mPhoneNumber, null, msgs, mPis, null);
```

Comment: Hello - I am still unable to resolve the issue. The first link in your answer addresses it by breaking up multipart into a number of single-part messages (i.e. bypasses the issue).The second link creates an ArrayList of SENT PendingIntents -- I tried that without success (even though as per the docs this can simply be null, same as the DELIVERED PendingIntent ArrayList). Can you confirm if the NullPointerException has gone away in your case, or are you just trapping it?